# is there a visual programming environment like Nifi or streamsets data collector for flink or beam-filnk

Tags: apache-flink, apache-beam, visual-programming

I am looking for a visual programming tool to abstract away coding when creating data stream flows to build CEP applications in Flink or Beam-Flink. Something like the Nifi or  streamsets data collector graphical designers.

Is anyone aware of such a project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, at the moment, there isn't such a visual pipeline construction tool readily available in the open source ecosystem.

That said, this isn't an unsolvable problem -- in Apache Beam, it is tracked via [BEAM-266](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-266), and it is conceivable that this becomes a part of the project in the medium term.

Outside the open source, there are commercial tools built on top of Apache Beam that provide something like this, but in a somewhat reduced domain (e.g., data preparation) -- check out tools by Talend, Google Cloud, and others.

Answer (score 2):

Right now there is a visual tool https://github.com/TouK/nussknacker.
The result of its flow execution is not exactly mapped into Flink Operator or Beam but Nussknacker nodes can be easily translated into similar Flink Operators. One Nussknacker scenario is deployed as a single Flink’s job. You can also add your custom components which will be translated even more straightforwardly to Flink’s Operators.
You don’t have full capabilities of Flink CEP but you can handle many CEP use cases using filter/switch/split/joint etc.